# Finding the byte-code

Tags: java, bytecode

How could one go about finding where in memory a running java program was storing the bytecode it was running off of? I appreciate this may or may not be excruciatingly difficult.

Comment: byte code is stored in .class files. What do you specifically mean?

Comment: when the program is running it is loaded from disk into memory, no? How can I find the byte-code stored in this '.class' file in memory?

Comment: It seems that you are not asking your "real" question. What is the problem you want to solve? If you would like to intercept the class loading there are probably better and easier solutions.

Comment: I want to call directly from another programming language directly into Java. Using two loops and a boolean I should be able to isolate one loop and hot swap the byte-code from under it. The thing is, I don't know where this byte-code is, nor how to find it.

Comment: Did you think about using regular JNI?

Comment: So what? Create bridge. If you can achieve your goal using "standard" way, do it. You can try to hack JVM but it is very hard and can fail. If JNI is not an option try byte code modification. There are a lot of tools. You can modify your java code at runtime and make it to call your code outside JVM instead of hacking JVM.

Comment: @providence let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2841/discussion-between-alexr-and-providence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source code for the native function `java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(String, byte[], int, int, ProtectionDomain, String, boolean)`

This is a VM specfic, so there is no general solution.

If you want to look at the byte code, just load the class as a resource (for example `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('java/lang/String.class')`) and analyze that stream with a tool like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) or similar.

If you want to modify the byte code at runtime: Good luck with that. The VM has been hardened against such attacks so even if you could get the memory location, chances are that changes would get caught.

Note that debuggers don't modify the memory, they use special class loaders (or features of the built in class loader) to return a different result when someone asks for a class when the source code has been changed in the IDE. But there are limits to that. Some VMs can't change the number and/or arguments of methods after a class has been loaded once, for example.

Comment: Hmm.. I don't need this to work on any machine other than my own, really. Is there a JVM that I could potentially fork/extend to allow this?

Comment: Sure: http://openjdk.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

You could try running the jvm with a debugger and then, right after a class has been loaded, search the allocated memory for the byte code pattern, that can be found in the loaded class file.

The jvm may decide to compile the byte code just in time and then it may decide to free the memory that was allocated for the byte code (because it's not needed anymore). So you may or may not find the byte code somewhere in memory.

Comment: Is it possible to take the same approach used to develop debugging tools to access this outside of debug mode?

Answer (score 1):

When the JVM reads the byte code, it massages it in a number of phases until finally it produces native code (which it may do more than once) Attempting to find somewhere is memory that the byte code is stored and altering it may not do anything because it may not use the byte code directly (nor even retain it)

If you want to change the byte code on the fly, I suggest you check it before it is loaded or use the Instrumentation which is designed to change byte code and will trigger the right behaviour when this happen.

The byte code is used virtually, there is no guarantee it means anything to the real machine (which is what you see at the "C" level)

Comment: How are byte-code representations of data + data-structures (lets say an array) passed into a running program? Can this these representations be generated externally and passed in from the outside at runtime?

Comment: @providence: Open a new question for this

Comment: @providence, The way to do this is to make the change as I suggested.  The approach you are taking it highly unlikely to work.  There is an incredible amount of optimisation that the JVM does at runtime and the notion of code is far more fluid than you appear to believe.

Comment: @providence, There are multiple structures used and these can change at any time.  The JVM can discard your changes which unpredictable results (assuming you understood exactly what to change in the first place). i.e. the interpreted/compiled code is not static at all. I have seen occasions where the same method is re-compiled many times in the same second (due to changing runtime behaviour)

Comment: Hmm, wow. Looks like this may prove to be extremely difficult

Comment: @providence, Unless you use the supported technique for byte code instrumentation in which case it is relatively easy. Its just VERY hard to do any other way.